# How to make a card with a specific and consistent design

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

In my web project, I'm trying to reproduce the following card:

[image]

When the Card is not active it is characterized by the fact that the image is always in the center even though the title has a dynamic height, and when its active (i.e it has the blue background) I don't want to change the height of the card but just to push the image up a little bit to add that extra space where the new round arrow button will appear and I'm completely unable to make this happen.

I'm using tailwind in a Nextjs project but plain and simple html and css would also be fine.

Comment: How far did you get when you tried? What representative "*[mcve]*" HTML, and CSS, did you come up with? Where did you fail, and in what way? Please take a moment to read the "*[ask]*" guidance to help you improve your question in a way that lets us answer it usefully for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use flexbox to align the content to the bottom of the card and give the text a fixed height when inactive to keep it at the same position regardless of whether it spans one or two lines.

To move everything up for the arrow you could render an arrow element below the text when he card is active and it would automatically push everything up. You could remove the fixed height of the text when active so there is no gap between the text and arrow. I have created an example here https://play.tailwindcss.com/7h1IY8alDQ.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="flex h-screen space-x-4 bg-blue-100 p-6">
  <!-- card 1 -->
  <div class="group flex h-32 w-32 flex-col items-center justify-end space-y-2 rounded-lg border-4 border-white bg-white p-2 hover:border-[#5691C3] hover:bg-[#80B2D5]">
    <!-- icon -->
    <div class="h-10 w-10 bg-gray-300 group-hover:bg-white"></div>
    <!-- title -->
    <p class="h-8 text-center text-xs text-black group-hover:h-auto group-hover:text-white group-hover:underline">Motor</p>
    <!-- arrow -->
    <div class="relative hidden h-4 w-4 shrink-0 items-center justify-center rounded-full border-2 border-white text-sm group-hover:flex"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- card 2 -->
  <div class="group flex h-32 w-32 flex-col items-center justify-end space-y-2 rounded-lg border-4 border-white bg-white p-2 hover:border-[#5691C3] hover:bg-[#80B2D5]">
    <!-- icon -->
    <div class="h-10 w-10 bg-gray-300 group-hover:bg-white"></div>
    <!-- title -->
    <p class="h-8 text-center text-xs text-black group-hover:h-auto group-hover:text-white group-hover:underline">Workmen Compensation</p>
    <!-- arrow -->
    <div class="relative hidden h-4 w-4 shrink-0 items-center justify-center rounded-full border-2 border-white text-sm group-hover:flex"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```